# this.state.something mutated and caused issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For some reason I can't do this

```
this.state.something.map(obj => obj.id)
```

because it caused extra rerendering. How to get something from state, without assign it to a new variable?

I used to do this ugly hack

```
something_state_holder = this.state.something
something_state_holder.map(obj => obj.id)
```

but is there any better / more elegant way?

Comment: `this.state.something.map(obj => obj.id)`  will not affect the `state` value, it's a proper way of iterating the `state` values to create ui or to do some calculations.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? `map` doesn't mutate, it creates a new array from your initial array.

Answer (score 1):

As @mayank-shukla said, what you are doing here is perfectly valid. The `map()` method iterates through an array and returns and array, but without mutating the iterated one. Here's what the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control) says:

> The **`map()`** method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.
>
> **`map`** does not mutate the array on which it is called (although callback, if invoked, may do so).

However, should you want to make a shallow copy on an array, you could use slice:

```
something_state_holder = this.state.something.slice();
var resulting_array = something_state_holder.map(obj => obj.id);
```

This iterates through the copy, and not the state. What you did is not creating an array, you are simply assigning the reference to the same array to a new variable. So mutating that will mutate the state.